# asp.net MVC4 - update database where id=given

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I update a row in my database including where clause?

my c# codes-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string ID, string notes)
    {
        SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();

        // update table name Customers, set row `customerNote` with passed string notes, where `id` == given string ID


        return View();
    }
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: I recommend walking through an introductory tutorial on the data access technology you're using.  (Linq to SQL?  Entity Framework?)  This is basic functionality.  Essentially you find the object instance in the DB context, update its properties, and save the changes on the DB context.

Comment: see this tutorial series from msdn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(string ID, string notes)
    {
        SampleDBContext dbContext = new SampleDBContext();
        var customer= dbContext .Customers.Where(e=>e.ID =ID )
        if (customer.ID == default(System.Guid)) {
            // New entity
            customer.UID = Guid.NewGuid();
            dbContext .customers.Add(customer);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            dbContext .Entry(customer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
      dbContext .SaveChanges();
    }
```

1. Get data row from table.
2. Update data as per need
3. Save changes are required to save the data in table.

Comment: @SakirKhan its a general approach. you can use Scaffolding to write repositories.

Answer (score 0):

your data will update like

```
public ActionResult Demoupdate(int id,EmployeeModel emp)

        Employee emptbl = new Employee();
        var data = (from t in dbc.Employees where t.EmpId == id select t).FirstOrDefault();

        if (data != null)
        {
            emp.EmpName = data.EmpName;
            emp.EmpAddress = data.EmpAddress;
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Demoupdate(EmployeeModel emp, int id)
    {
        Employee emptbl = new Employee();
        emptbl.EmpId = id;
        emptbl.EmpName = emp.EmpName;
        emptbl.EmpAddress = emp.EmpAddress;
        dbc.Entry(emptbl).State = EntityState.Modified;
        dbc.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```