# Can add a new record to db table but cant update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-4

Using MVC 4 to create a web application. Have added new records to the DB tables using:

```
Bicycle_Order bicycle_order = order_VM.Order;

BuyABicycle_Entities db1 = new BuyABicycle_Entities();

BicycleOrder NewOrder = new BicycleOrder();
//populate the rest of NewOrder

db1.AddEntity(NewOrder);

db1.SaveChanges();
```

This works fine, however I cant find the correct option to allow me to update an existing record. So far I have tried the following examples but cant get it to work:

```
if (_bik.Shipped != bik.Shipped)
{
_bik.Shipped = bik.Shipped;

//UPDATE _bik
//db1.HasChanges(_bik);
//db1.EntityChanged(_bik).State = EntityState.Modified;
//db1.Entry(_bik).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; ;
}
}

db1.SaveChanges();
```

I have been looking online but cant find a resolve. please advise what I am doing wrong

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894748/asp-net-mvc4-update-database-where-id-given
```

**UPDATE**
By pure chance I noticed I dont need to do anyform of db1.Update(_bik), as db1.SaveChanges(); saves the changes anyway. Is this correct? Shouldnt there be some form of manual update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you have update errors it can be a few things. Check your datatypes make sure that non null able values are not null, also make sure that if you have any relationships set up your are not missing any required ids or parameters. If you could provide errors or stack trace I can be of more assistance.

Comment: I wasnt sure of the errors because I wasnt sure which extension in the telesense I was meant to be using after db1...in order to update the changes to _bik, but for some reason I dont need to, db1.SaveChanges() saves it all...Is this new? I only downloaded mvc4 2 days ago. this must be an update with it?

Comment: Yes there have been a few changes with mvc. Breakpoints still work in mvc place your code in a try catch statement and either use Response.write(Ex.message) return null; Or place a breakpoint on the catch to recieve more detailed information on the entity validation errors. I had to do some research when getting started with the new version my self.

Comment: Have you tried generating your controller and view from the model ? This will automatically avoid such issues because visual studio writes the code for you.